# i want to enable javascript in the pop up box

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

i get some error with my pop up cannot show page,i want to make a pop up from external my page, i do not want my page will join with internal code so i make pop up and include my external without change external code. here is some code that i used to..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').load("google.com");
});
```

```css
> here is my css style for my codestrong text

  .modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);

}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div>
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

  <div id="content">
   <p>my external page should be here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I can’t see that from the information you’ve given.

Comment: the pop up cannot show external page, an example i want to pop up google.com with my code

Comment: You’ll need an iframe to do that.

Comment: no iframe that i need, just pop up show in primary page dont make a new tab,

Comment: So you are wanting a pop up box to display another web page?

Comment: yes bro, another web page pop up in current page

Comment: Then you’ll need an iframe.